Why does my car need more gasoline when it is cold outside?
Why does my car need more gasoline when it is cold outside?
It does, as well as the car before, and the car before that.
Carnot's rule states that the engine runs more efficiently when the temperature difference increases, but what I see on cars, the miles per gallon does not increase but decreases significantly.
OK, I have seen Does a car consume more fuel when it's raining? and considered this aspect before.
What I observe is that temperature decreases miles per gallon even on dry roads.
Why so?
(If someone knows additional tags, you're welcome.)

Many places add ethanol in the winter, which has less energy per volume than gas.

@JonCuster I experienced this effect even time back when no ethanol was added, but that could be an additional reason in our perverted times when food is converted to energy instead of energy being converted to food.

Reducing smog is a good thing too…

You might want to look at the many reasons fuel economy is reduced in cold weather (https://www.fueleconomy.gov/FeG/coldweather.shtml), and focus the question on a specific physics issue. Note that "Are internal combustion engines more efficient on cold days?" has already been asked.

@JonCuster "Reducing smog is a good thing too… " right, and even more so not adding lead. But, does ethanol really decrease smog?

Yes, the OH group of an alcohol does that.

How cold? If the tire pressure decreases during cold weather the change in wheel/tire radius might affect the odometer reading.

@StevanV.Saban the change is observable by 10°C, but I don't know how much this changes the odometer. I experienced the effect on refueling, which should be independent on any nowadays gadgets.

@JonCuster "Yes, the OH group of an alcohol does that."  ... at the cost of consuming more gasoline to cancel the effect. No gain.

@GyroGearloose The net effect is in fact a reduction of certain pollutants; the pollutant reduction due to ethanol is a bit more than the increase due to increased fuel usage. || Separately, another thing that could cause increased gas usage in winter is simply running the heater--heaters require more power than you might think to operate, and the majority of people do use the one in their car when it gets cold. It's not that significant in comparison to moving a thousand or two pounds of car around, but it does add some fuel consumption.

@Hearth it has to be very cold for me to start the heater. When I do, it is mostly because the screens are fogging. For the aspect of ethanol and pollution, this is growing into a discussion and this is not the place for it, yet I'm interested. Where could that go on?


Carnot's rule states that the engine runs more efficiently when the
temperature difference increases, but what I see on cars, the miles
per gallon does not increase but decreases significantly.

The Carnot cycle involves no dissipative losses, such as friction.
On the other hand, a gasoline engine has losses, some of which are greater in colder weather. Examples are the greater thickness (and thus friction) of engine oil when the car is first started, and longer times for an engine to reach its optimal operating temperature. There is also the lower fuel efficiency associated with winter blends of fuel.
There are other inefficiencies in winter that are non engine related, such as greater air drag in colder weather, and lower tire pressure if not adjusted for the cold weather conditions.
Hope this helps.

I have experienced this effect on long distances, about the way what a fully filled car can run, and, without stopping.

On friction, I guess the car manufactures have a problem to decide on how much to thermally insulate the frictional parts: too less, and they would not warm up on short distance. Too much, and there will be more serious problems on long journeys in hot weather. And temperature sensitive materials  that are insulating at low temperatures and conductive at high temperatures are too expensive.

@GyroGearloose FWIW I recall an ideal Otto  cycle efficiency would be greater in cold weather
